# rails_admin polymorphic association field sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, rails-admin

I like sort 'owner' field by first_name and name in rails_admin.

```
    Document.rb
    belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

    User.rb
    has_many: documents, as: :owner

    Group.rb
    has_many :documents, as: :owner

    rails_admin do 
      list do 
        field :owner
      end
      create do 
        field :owner
      end
    end
```

This will give the list of owners order by id but I would like to sort by User's first name and Group's name. How to approach this?

In rails_admin.rb, I tried:

```
     config.model Document do 
      field :owner do 
       associated_collection_cache_all false
       associated_collection_scope do 
         startups = bindings[:object]
         Proc.new { |scope|
          scope = scope.all.sort { |a, b| a.name <=> b.name }
         }
       end
     end
   end
```

This doesn't work. FYI. You can't use 'order' operation so I used sort instead.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping

Comment: I updated my question with the solution you pointed out. I tried but it doesn't work. Do you see the reason?